# Standard notation for indices in group theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation

I've seen three notations for indices in group theory, namely $(G:H)$, $[G:H]$ and $|G:H|$.

Is there any of these notations that is standard?

Comment: At least the first two are standard. Not sure whether the third is also standard.

Comment: @DanielFischer I see. The third one is the most used on Wikipedia.

Comment: The second one is most standard "in my world". The first one would be intelligible, but cause me to wonder. The third I have never seen used for this purpose.

Comment: I'm no expert in abstract algebra. But I've definitely seen the second one and third one. First one looks strange to me, haha. I personally prefer the second one.

Comment: Bourbaki denotes it $\;(G:H)$.

Comment: The books of the group theory authorities (B. Huppert, I.M. Isaacs, D.J.S. Robinson, J. Rose) all use the last one. The straight lines reflect the cardinality of a set, in this case the number of cosets. Similarly, $|G|$ is used for the order (cardinality) of the group $G$. I myself sometimes use another one: index$[G:H]$ too. I certainly would not use the first one with the round brackets. But that is maybe the French school against the Anglo-Saxon conventions.

Comment: @paul garrett: there may be a problem with the second notation in Galois theory; the degree of an extension field $L/K$ is denoted $L:K]$  and the same notation for the index of a subgroup  may be confusional when used with Galois groups.

Comment: @Bernard, I'd hope that "type checking" (i.e., context) in the formal-language sense would easily allow one to distinguish where it was a field extension degree or a group index. And, for my eyes, the plain vertical bars cause far more trouble with my astigmatism than the brackets. Parentheses are not so great, either. :)

Comment: That's why I prefer Bourbaki's notation. One should look also in van der Waerden. Btw, Milne follows Bourbaki's convention.

Comment: Dummit and Foote use the 3rd notation for groups and reserve the 2nd notation for the degree of a field extension.